# How to add a force line-break in a draw2d TextFlow

Tags: swt, line-breaks, draw2d, zest, textflow

How do I add a forced line-break within a draw2d `TextFlow` figure.

I build a `IFigure` by adding several different objects. Amongst other things I add a `FlowPage` containing a `TextFlow`. But I could not find an option to force line-breaks at specific locations.

```java
Figure fig = new Figure();
fig.setLayoutManager(new FreeformLayout());

FlowPage flow = new FlowPage();
flow.setSize(100,100);

TextFlow text = new textFlow("A rather long text without any line-breaks. Lorem Ipsum dolor sit amet.");

flow.add(text);
fig.add(flow);
fig.setSite(100,100);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The common LineFeed character `\n` solved this problem. Inserted somewhere inside the String it forces a line-break.